# hit for "snow" on Google image -> Does it make sense?

Tags: american-english

My friend told me to hit for "snow" on Google image. I don't understand what that means.

I think it means searching for "snow" on Google image. Does it make sense?

Comment: My wild guess is that "hit for something on Google Images" might be influenced by or borrowed from gaming. I think in some shooting games, the players actually need to "hit" many things that wouldn't reflect the real world, and the "for" might come in because the player might actually need to "hunt for" those things they want to "hit" (for example, power, speed, new weapons, ammo, upgrades, etc.); but this is only my wildest guess. ;-)

Comment: these days the word *hit* is often used to press the **Enter** key. The friend might mean type 'snow' and **hit** (Enter) on Google Images. However, I'd not prefer it personally ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense.  Usually we'd say something like this:

> Search for "snow" on Google images.

or

> Do a Google image search for "snow".

We wouldn't normally use the word *hit* the way your friend did.  Perhaps your friend was trying to turn the phrase *Google hits* (meaning "search results on Google") into a verb, but in my opinion they were not successful in doing so.

Comment: +1 Or, just possibly, "Hit Google Image for *snow*".